# bash if with or and negation

Tags: bash

why does:

```
#!/bin/bash
wtf=false
if [ $wtf ] || [ ! -f filethatexists.whatever ]
then
 echo "WTF1"
fi
if [ ! -f filethatexists.whatever ]
then
 echo "WTF2"
fi
```

print:

WTF1

instead of nothing? It is especially perplexing that the second form works as expected and the first not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic test

```
[ $wtf ]
```

tests whether the string in the middle is empty or not.

Since `$wtf` contains the string `'false'`, the test returns true, or exit status 0 for success, because `'false'` is not the same as the empty string `''` — and hence you get `WTF1` as the response.

Try with:

```
wtf=''
```

---

As pointed out by [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) (and [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson)), it is a good idea to be careful with strings that you are testing.  Indeed, I should have stated that I would always use `[ -n "$wtf" ]` or `[ -z "$wtf" ]` to test whether a variable is set, because that was necessary when I was learning shell, once upon a quarter century ago.  I've had counter stories from Bash afficionados that you don't have to worry about it in Bash - however, I think the code here provides a counter-example that in fact you do still have to worry about it.

So, some best practices:

- Enclose tested variables in double quotes, or
- (In Bash), use `[[ $wtf ]]` which does know how to handle the variable expansion.
- Use the `-n` or `-z` tests to test for non-empty or empty values.

There can be exceptions to the rules - but you will not go far wrong following them.

Consider the code:

```
wtf="1 -eq 0"
 [  $wtf  ]  && echo "WTF0"
[[  $wtf  ]] && echo "WTF1"
wtf="false"
 [  $wtf  ]  && echo "WTF2"
[[  $wtf  ]] && echo "WTF3"
wtf=""
 [  $wtf  ]  && echo "WTF4"
[[  $wtf  ]] && echo "WTF5"
wtf="false"
 [ "$wtf" ]  && echo "WTF6"
[[ "$wtf" ]] && echo "WTF7"
wtf=""
 [ "$wtf" ]  && echo "WTF8"
[[ "$wtf" ]] && echo "WTF9"
```

That produces:

```
WTF1
WTF2
WTF3
WTF6
WTF7
```

with both bash and ksh (as found on MacOS X 10.6.4, when run with 'bash testcode.sh' or 'ksh testcode.sh').  A real Bourne shell (if you can still find such a thing) would object to the double-bracket operations - it would not be able to find the command '`[[`' on `$PATH`.

You can extend the testing to cover more cases ad nauseam.

Comment: ok, makes sense. The syntax highlighting made me thing that booleans were a given. Guess i expected too much.

Comment: Actually, it's even weirder than that -- if $wtf has any spaces in it, it'll be evaluated as an expression.  Try it with `wtf="1 -eq 0"` and `wtf="1 -eq 1` to see the effect.  For even more comedy, try `wtf="1 -eq"`

Comment: Test 4/5 is a duplicate of test 8/9. I think you meant to do 4/5 without quotes around the variable (but the result is the same - nothing is echoed). Also, test 0/1 altered by quoting the variable doesn't evaluate the `1 -eq 0` so both bracket types evaluate to true (as in test 2/3). Interestingly, in Bash and ksh, `[ '' ]`, `[[ '' ]]` and `[ ]` each work, and return false, however `[[ ]]` produces an error.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a handy little trick:

```
wtf=false
if $wtf || [ ! -f filethatexists.whatever ]
```

In this form, the contents of the variable are executed and the return value determines whether the test passes or fails. It happens that `true` and `false` are Bash builtins that return the appropriate value.

Comment: This "handy little trick" is hardly good practice. If you have a codepath where `wtf` contains anything other than `true` or `false`, surprising behavior results. Empty string? Prior value of `$?` carries over! `rm -rf /`? Err...

Answer (score 0):

`if [ $wtf = true ] || [ ! -f . .`

Comment: or even "if [[ $wtf == true ]] || [ ! -f ..."

Comment: @dimba That's a bashism, though, & you can't run it outside of bash or a bash-compatiable shell.